# Transform array of array into NumPy's ndarray of ndarrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to transform an array of arrays with a numpy ndarray of ndarrays.

This is my dtype:

```
dt = 'i8,i8,i8,i8,i8,i8,i8,i8,i8,i8,i8,i8,i8,f8,i8,i8,f8,f8,f8,a50,a50,a50,a50'
```

And this is my data:

```
# data array reduced to one row for sake of readability
data = [[45608L, 0L, 46115L, 11952L, 11952L, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11951L, 11951L, 46176L, 9.0, 0, 1, 1407340577.0, 1407340577.0, 0, 'Simulation Movement', 'planned', '', ''],]
```

I already tried these ways:

```
np.array(data, dt)
np.array([np.array(row, dt) for row in data])
```

But when I run both these I get:

`TypeError: expected a readable buffer object`

Buuuuut, if I call `np.array` with an array only containing each single element of my rows and using the appropriate data type (did this using a loop with enumerate and a split `dt`) , it works. Was something like this:

```
for row in data:
  for index, value in enumerate(row):
    np.array([value,], dt.split(',')[index])
```

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like for this to work, you would need to convert the inner list into tuple. Example -

```
import numpy as np

dt = 'i8,i8,i8,i8,i8,i8,i8,i8,i8,i8,i8,i8,i8,f8,i8,i8,f8,f8,f8,a50,a50,a50,a50'

data = [[45608L, 0L, 46115L, 11952L, 11952L, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11951L, 11951L, 46176L, 9.0, 0, 1, 1407340577.0, 1407340577.0, 0, 'Simulation Movement', 'planned', '', ''],]

result = np.array(map(tuple, data),dt)
```

Demo run [here](https://ideone.com/keEDBt). But with this you get an array of 1 element back `shape = (1,)` (the 1 element being the tuple).

---

You can also use `'object'` as the dtype, [Example -](https://ideone.com/Aq7kNK)

```
result1 = np.array(data,'object')
```

Even though this does result in an array with correct shape , some things may not work because of the mixed types (but I guess you expect that).